# Bootstrap 4 Navigation Bar Dropdown Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to split this navigation bar dropdown menu in to two columns but they clash with each other.

And the other issue is, the Search bar stays at bottom when in mobile. And page is not responsive. I don't know if this is caused by navigation bar issue.  Any input would be appreciated. I hope you all have a great weekend!

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;

}








 section {
     padding: 70px 0;
     border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
 .grid-example div[class^="col"] {
     border: 1px solid white;
     background: lightblue;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-bottom: 8px;
}
 .jumbotron {
     background-color: lightskyblue;
}
 table th {
     text-align: center;
}
 .table {
     margin: auto;
     width: 50% !important;
}
 .table td {
     text-align: center;
}
 .footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     line-height: 60px;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
 a {
     color: #f00;
}
 a:hover {
     color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sticky Footer.css">

    


   

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #C0C0C0;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Test
        </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:300px" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <div class="container container-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test Test Test</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test Test</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">itemitemitemitem</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">itemitemitemitemitem</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item</a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-8">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead-8">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>









    <div class="row align-items-center" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 500px);">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">

                <input id='urlurl' type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" pattern="https?://.+" required />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #0275D8; border-color: #0275D8;" type="button" >Test</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <footer class="footer fixed-bottom text-center">
        <span class="text">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </footer>



    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the dropdown question that goes along with the title.
You don't want to nest a `container` inside of the dropdown. Also increase the `min-width` on the dropdown to fit the content.

https://codeply.com/go/9wUCwUErKL

```
       <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width:360px" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">Test Test Test</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">Test Test</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">Test</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">itemitemitemitem</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">itemitemitemitemitem</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">item</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
       </div>
```

There is no longer `col-xs-*` in Bootstrap 4, it's just `col-*`.